# Red/System binding for 3D graphics on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opengl-es, raspberry-pi, rebol3, red, red-system

For someone getting started with Red/System programming on the Raspberry Pi, what is the best way to access the GPU for 3D rendering?  Can this method also be used for Rebol3 on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My OpenGL binding for Red/System would be the starting point:

http://red.esperconsultancy.nl/Red-OpenGL

I'm currently working on extending it for the Raspberry Pi. The current binding is for desktop OpenGL. For Raspberry Pi and other small platforms, I'm working on an OpenGL-ES binding. Further, OpenGL needs an environment on the target platform. The binding has several backends, such as SDL, but these don't work on the Raspberry Pi as it uses EGL in combination with its own environment as defined by Broadcom. I'm also working on extra backends for those.

Bindings for Red, including this one when Raspberry Pi support is finished, can be used to base REBOL 3 extensions on, with my Red/REBOL 3 bridge:

http://red.esperconsultancy.nl/Red-REBOL-3

However, writing such an extension is an extra effort.

Comment: Have you put this on github? I am asking because the link no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

The site in the answer by Kaj de Vos is no longer works.

You may find its mirror useful:
https://github.com/red/RS-fossil-mirror

Or the red/code repository:
https://github.com/red/code/tree/master/Library/OpenGL